# How to use cascade in Hibernate ManyToMany to skip duplicates?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, cascade

I have two entities: Tag and Topic. They have many-to-many relationship(tables: tags, topics, tags_topics).
I want following rules:

- when I save topic - tags are saved too.
- when I save next topic with same tag(s) - topic saved, but tags that are already exist - dont save, and in tags_topics saved new relationship.
- when I delete topic - tags are not deleting.

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tags_topics",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "topic_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
```

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Topic> topics = new HashSet<>();
```

If I try to create new topic with same tag, I receive `duplicate key value violates the uniqueness constraint of tags_name_key`.

When I use CascadeType.MERGE:

`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

then I do:

```
cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
```

And again `duplicate key value violates the uniqueness constraint of tags_name_key`.

my http POST request example:

```
{
  "subject": "ManyToMany",
  "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask",
  "description": "Code",
  "readStatus": false,
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "jpa"
    },
    {
      "name": "manytomany"
    }
  ]
}
```

saving code:

```
public TopicDto saveTopic(TopicDto dto){
    return topicMapper.toDto(repository.save(topicMapper(toEntity(dto)));
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code with which the saving is done?

Comment: @InsertKnowledge edited question